# What happens when gadget gets 100% charged

Tags: battery-charging, charging, mobile

We see that when our mobile phones, laptops, i-pads, or any other electronic gadget requiring charging, gets completely charged it starts displaying that it has stopped charging like in my HTC phone the led glows red while it is charging and turns green when completely charged. So basically today's gadgets have some kind of mechanism to show that after a certain point of time they have stopped charging.

Now my question is, if the device is showing that it is taking no power but we have not unplugged it, so where exactly is the power going. Is it so that they display 100% charged some time before it is exactly 100% charged...or whatever...

Comment: "where exactly is the power going" what power are you talking about? all the power that the device consumes and is not emitted as e.g. light is converted into heat, but that doesnt have to do anything with charging.

Comment: No i mean the power which we are supplying from the mains which it used to charge itself to 100%!!!!!

Comment: There is no power forced upon the device, it draws the current it needs, not more.

Comment: Ok lemme try and clarify this a bit. Our phones battery gets fully charged but we are still supplying the power. The phone is sitting idle(even though it is consuming some power then also). But is the power supplied from mains not used by the phone at all?

Comment: Disconnect your charger from the phone. Look closely at the plug. Do you see any electrons falling out?

Comment: ok..i understand you are being sarcastic here. So if you don't have anything to share you can just stop responding .

Comment: I just went out of options to try explaining that the devices draws the amount of power it needs, not that the charger is pushing it through the cable and whatever is at the other end has to swallow it.

Comment: Water analogy: Voltage is similar to pumping pressure. Current flow = current flow. POwer = pressure (pumping head) x flow. If a pump makes pressure but there is no flow there is no power (or energy) transferred. Water taps have pressurised water behind them but until something else causes the pressure tpo cause flow there is no power transferred.

Answer (score 3):

The device contains a power circuit that allows it to charge the battery and also power the device itself using the energy coming from the cable. The charging part of the power circuit monitors the battery state and decides whether the battery can be charged and how that should be done exactly (LiPO batteries require extreme care when charging - blindly trying to charge a battery that is fully or almost charged causes dire consequences).

So in your scenario... you connect the cable while the battery is not fully charged, part of energy from the cable is used to power the device and part is used to drive the charging circuit. Then the battery gets charged and the charging circuit stops charging the battery and you see "battery full" message in one form or another. From that moment energy coming from the cable is only used to power the device, not the battery.

Comment: ok...this seems a pretty reasonable explanation. Do you know some kind of resource where this might be given in much detail?

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi No, I myself often have hard time finding any resources with layman explanations. Maybe you can find a circuit diagram for some laptop power distribution circuits.

Answer (score 3):

To clear up a possible misunderstanding -

The output rating of a cell phone charger (or any sort of power supply) is the maximum current the supply is designed to supply.  The power supply does not force that current into the phone or other load.  The phone will only draw the current it needs from the charger.  When the battery is discharged, the phone will likely draw nearly the full rated output from the charger.  As the battery approaches full charge, the phone will draw less current from the charger, and the charger will draw less current from the AC mains.

Answer (score 1):

When the battery is fully charged, all the power from the mains is used to power the device.

You can find plenty of information about several different battery charging methods and configurations at the website of TI:

http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/powermanagement/technical-documents.page

At the pdf "battery management solutions"

Hope it helps to understand